# How to extend this PDE?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

Let $(M^n,g)$ and $(N^m,h)$ be Riemann manifolds without boundary of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively and $u:(M^n,g)\to (N^m,h)$ be a map satisfying the following PDE on $M^n\backslash\Sigma$ ($u$ is smooth on $M^n\backslash\Sigma$ )

$\Delta_gu+A(\nabla u,\nabla u)=f(x,u,\nabla u)$,

where $A$ denotes the second fundamental form of $N^m\subset \mathbb{R}^Q$ (by Nash's embedding theorem), $\Delta_g$ denotes the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $(M^n,g)$, $f$ is a smooth function defined on the whole $M^n$ with linear dependence on $\nabla u$  and $\Sigma$ is a $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}-$dimensional set $($Here $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}$ denotes the $(n-2)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $(M^n,g))$.

It is easy to check $u$ satisfies the weak formulation of this PDE, that is

$\int\nabla u\nabla\varphi+A(\nabla u,\nabla u)\varphi=\int f(x,u,\nabla u)\varphi$ on $M^n$,

if we take the test functions in $C_c^\infty(M^n\backslash\Sigma)$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ This PDE can extend across $\Sigma$ by a standard capacity argument such that $u$ satisfies the weak formulation of this PDE globally, i.e. we can allow the test functions $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(M^n)$. How to do it?

I guess the linearity may be crucial in such extension argument. Because this argument can't be applied to a non-linear PDE, called "stationary" PDE for weakly harmonic maps. Otherwise, it will contradict with a well-known fact: the limit map of a weakly converging $($in sobolev space $W^{1,2}(M^n,N^m))$ sequence of stationary harmonic maps may not be stationary. But it is still a weakly harmonic map (This is a direct corollary of this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer that assumes the stronger condition that $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(\Sigma)<\infty$.

To simplify the notation I will show that if $u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \Sigma$, with $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(\Sigma)<\infty$, then $u$ can be extended to a harmonic function on all $\mathbb{R}^n$. The adaptation to the specific setting of your question should follow from the same idea (I haven't checked the details).

So note that $\mathcal{H}^{n-2}(\Sigma)<\infty$ implies $Cap_2(\Sigma)=0$ (see *Evans, Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions, Theorem 4.16, second edition*) hence there is a sequence of cutoffs $\eta_j$ with $\eta_j\equiv 1$ on a neighborhood of $\Sigma$ and with $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |D\eta_j|^2 \to 0$. By Poincaré ($\star$) hence $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\eta_j|^2 \to 0$. Hence given a test function $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\langle D\phi, Du \rangle|&=|\langle D(\phi \eta_j)+D(\phi (1-\eta_j)),Du \rangle|\\
&=|\langle D(\phi \eta_j),Du \rangle|\\
&=|\langle(D\phi)\eta_j+\phi D\eta_j, u \rangle| \\
&\leq  ||u||_{L^2}(||D\phi||_{L^{\infty}} ||\eta_j||_{L^2} + ||\phi||_{L^{\infty}} ||D\eta_j||_{L^2}),
\end{aligned}
$$
which goes to $0$ and we used that $\langle D(\phi (1- \eta_j)),Du \rangle=0$ (which is true because $\phi (1- \eta_j)$ has compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \Sigma$ and hence it can be approximated in $W^{1,2}$ by test functions).

($\star$) To be fully precise one cannot apply the standard Poincaré  here, since $\eta_j$ does not need to be in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but only in $L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. However, it is easy to see that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\eta_j|^{2^*} \leq C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |D\eta_j|^2$ (Theorem 4.12 in Evans), and since in the chain of inequalities $\eta_j$ appears only multiplied by the compactly-supported $D\phi$, everything still follows.